# Min value of array returns as 0

Tags: java, arrays, min

I'm having problems figuring out why returns for my minimum value in my array keep ending up as 0. I've checked several questions with the same problem but can't use those solutions because my array is being created in one method and my min/max values are calculated in another method.

Is there anyway I can keep my min/max value in a separate method and still get a non-zero answer for my min value?  Also, there is more code in the processSalesReport method but I left it out because it was irrelevant. Thanks ahead of time!

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CarSalesReport {

int sum;
int count = 0;
int[] num = new int[1500];
String ans = "";
Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

public CarSalesReport(Scanner input) {
    String regex = "\\d+|done";
    System.out.println("Type sales (type \"done\" when finished)");

    do{
        System.out.print("Sale Number " + (count + 1) +  ": ");
        ans = userInput.nextLine();
        while(!ans.matches(regex)){
            System.out.println("Please enter a positive number");
            ans = userInput.nextLine();
        }
        if(!ans.equalsIgnoreCase("done")){
            int ans1 = Integer.parseInt(ans);
            num[count] = ans1;
            count++;
        }           
    }while(!ans.equalsIgnoreCase("done"));
}

public void processSalesReport(){
    int max = num[0];
    for(int a=0;a<num.length;a++){
        if(max<num[a]){
            max=num[a];
        }
    }
    //This is where I'm having my problems.  
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for(int a=1;a<num.length;a++){
        if(min>num[a]){
            min=num[a];
        } 
    } 
    Arrays.sort(num);
    System.out.println("\nMaximum sale: $" + max); 
    System.out.println("\nMinimum sale: $" + min);

}
}
```

Comment: What are you expecting min to be?

Comment: If you step through this code with a debugger, you will see immediately what is happening.  Learning to use a debugger is an important part of learning to be a programmer.

Comment: I was expecting the min to be the smallest number that the user inputs.  It could only be 0 if the user writes 0.

And thanks David W! I just started learning Java last week and I didn't even think about debuggers.  I'll definitely look into that.  I'm surprised my instructor hasn't brought it up yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because you've got 1500 entries in your array, which are all initialised to 0.  You're iterating through all of them trying to find the minimum, instead of just iterating through the ones you've explicitly populated.

In the loop where you calculate the minimum, change

```
for (int a = 1; a < num.length; a++) {
```

to

```
for (int a = 0; a < count; a++) {
```

so that you only look at the entries that you've populated.